# css3: Transform animation for pseudo element

Tags: html, css, animation

I try to rotate :before element but it won't rotate. Please, tell me, what I'm doing wrong.

http://jsfiddle.net/holden321/h7eEB/

HTML:

```
<div>hello</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    height:25px;
    line-height:25px;
    padding-left:35px;
    position:relative;
}

div:before {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    left:0;top:0;
    height:25px;
    width:25px;
    background:url(http://lorempixel.com/20/20/) no-repeat center;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -webkit-animation: rotate 2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate { 
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forgot the `prefix` in the animation property `transform`:

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotate { 
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } 
}
```

Working **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h7eEB/3/)**

*Edit* : To make the `iteration-count` work change the order in CSS, first set the animation and then his properties:

```
-webkit-animation: rotate 2s; /*This First*/
-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
-webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
```

The **[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4z338/)**

Comment: Yes, yes, I have just seen it after posting))

Comment: There's no repeating though :(

Comment: @holden321 now infinite loop

Comment: Yes, indeed, it is strange that order is important. Thanks!